# Workbench not allowing to add Primary Index

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following defined in MySQL Workbench for a database table, say for example `table1`:

```
Index Name = PRIMARY Type = PRIMARY
```

I have created a similar separate table with name `table1_test` and trying to create same Index with same Index Type but it's not letting me choose
 PRIMARY from the dropdown menu? What could be the reason?

Comment: Why can't you just run an `ALTER` command?

Comment: You can only have one primary key in a table. If you already have one, it won't let you add another one. You can have multiple UNIQUE keys, though.